# Vuex - [Vue warn]: Error in render: "TypeError: this.$store is undefined"

Tags: vue.js, vuex

Mi store me esta dando error cuando llamo al mapState.

Mi **store.js** es :

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import Vuex from 'vuex'

Vue.use(Vuex);

const store = new Vuex.Store({
    state:{
        showLoader:false
    },
    mutations:{
        toggleShowLoader(state,visible){
            state.showLoader = visible;
        }
    }
});

export default store
```

Mi **App.vue** :

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <RegisterForm></RegisterForm>
    <div
      v-show="showLoader"
      @showLoader="toggleShowLoader(true)"
      @hideLoader="toggleShowLoader(false)"
    >
      <half-circle-spinner
            :animation-duration="1000"
            :size="120"
            color="#ff1d5e"
            style="  position: fixed;
                    left: 50%;
                    top: 50%;
                    z-index: 9999;
                    margin:0 auto;
                    "
      />
    </div>
   
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import RegisterForm from './components/RegisterForm.vue'
import { HalfCircleSpinner } from 'epic-spinners'
import {mapState} from 'vuex'

export default {
  name: 'App',
  components: {
    RegisterForm,
    HalfCircleSpinner
},
data(){
  return{
    loader:{
      visible:false
    }
  }
},
  methods: {
  },
  computed:{
    ...mapState([
      'showLoader'
    ])
  }
}
</script>

<style>
#app {
  font-family: Avenir, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  /* text-align: center; */
  color: #2c3e50;
  /* margin-top: 60px; */
}

/* TRANSICION DE IZQUIERDA A DERECHA */

/* Enter and leave animations can use different */
/* durations and timing functions.              */
.slide-fade-enter-active {
  transition: all 1s ease;
}
.slide-fade-leave-active {
  transition: all .8s cubic-bezier(1.0, 0.5, 0.8, 1.0);
}
.slide-fade-enter, .slide-fade-leave-to
/* .slide-fade-leave-active below version 2.1.8 */ {
  transform: translateX(700px);
  opacity: 0;
}

/* TRANSICION DE MENOS A MAS */
.bounce-enter-active {
  animation: bounce-in .5s;
}
.bounce-leave-active {
  animation: bounce-in .5s reverse;
}
@keyframes bounce-in {
  0% {
    transform: scale(0);
  }
  50% {
    transform: scale(1.5);
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(1);
  }
}

</style>
```

Pues a la hora de usar el mapState me arroja los siguientes errores:

```
[Vue warn]: Error in render: "TypeError: this.$store is undefined"

TypeError: this.$store is undefined
```

Yo me he creado el store, que es el manejador de vuex, lo he exportado desde el fichero store/index.js y lo he importado y asignado en App.vue. Deberia de estar globalmente visible.

h3. Aclaracion del error.

El Error se esta generando en `App.vue` a la hora de usar, dentro de computed, el mapState.

h5. Tambien dejo el `main.js` , donde asigno el store del vuex a mi app de vuejs:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import 'es6-promise/auto'
import {store} from './store/index'

import { BootstrapVue, IconsPlugin } from 'bootstrap-vue'

// Import Bootstrap an BootstrapVue CSS files (order is important)
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css'
import 'bootstrap-vue/dist/bootstrap-vue.css'


Vue.config.productionTip = false
// Make BootstrapVue available throughout your project
Vue.use(BootstrapVue)
// Optionally install the BootstrapVue icon components plugin
Vue.use(IconsPlugin)


new Vue({
  render: h => h(App),
  store:store,
  mode:'history'
}).$mount('#app')
```

Comment: que es computed en tu store? nunca lo vi, y no esta en la documentacion...

Comment: @gbianchi He actualizado la pregunta, efectivamente era un error. Gracias. Pero no era el causante de este problema.

Answer (score 0):

Parece ya estar corregido, parecia ser por la forma de importar el `store` en `App.vue` , yo lo estaba haciendo de esta manera:

```
import {store} from './store/index'
```

Siendo la forma correcta:

```
import store from './store/index'
```